# Is this possible to prettify \(A_i\) to A_i (A<sub>i</sub>) in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, text-properties

I would like to prettify \(A_i\) to A<sub>i</sub>. Is this possible? I looked up the source of `org-match-substring-regexp` and tried to modify it, but no luck. any help?

Comment: `org-cdlatex` does that. But, maybe that is not what you want.

Comment: There's tons of prettification modes, one of them even made it into Emacs!

Comment: Note that `prettify-symbols-mode` can only prettify symbols (strings, actually) to a **single character** (see doc of variable `prettify-symbols-alist`).  So  you would need to find a character for A_i.  I don't know about other prettification modes.